# Accessing a user defined custom method from another Activity

Tags: android, methods, android-activity

I have `MyClass1 extends Activity {`
....

```
public void myMethod(String url){...//mystuffs..}  

}
```

And

```
MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {

....

//here call myMethod..

}
```

But i am unable to call myMethod. It is giving me error before building the project saying "create method myMethod".

super.myMethod gives me following exception :

```
 W/dalvikvm(3211): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)  
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
java.lang.StackOverflowError   
Activity.loadUrl(MyClass1.java:119)  
MyClass2.onCreate(MyClass2.java:92)
```

any solution??

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: You want to call a method in a class body? Aren't you missing something?

Comment: super.myMethod i have tried. but it is giving me the edited exception in question.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
public class A extends Activity{

public void myMethod(String url){...//mystuffs..

}  

}

public class B extends A {

public void myMethod(String url){
super.myMethod(url);

}  

}
```